# What's the significance of the word "Gauḍīya" in Gauḍīya Vaiṣhṇavism?

Tags: krishna, history, gaudiya-vaishnavism

What's the etymological significance of the word "Gauḍīya" in Gauḍīya Vaiṣhṇavism?

Why is it specifically called Gauḍīya? Is it something specifically related to Śhrī Kriṣhṇa?
Is Gauḍīya Vaiṣhṇavism purely a Kriṣhṇaism sect, or one of its smaller subsets?

Please give the related historical, theological, ontological, (etc.)., significance of the word "Gauḍīya" and how it's interpreted by the relevant sect.

Comment: Gauda refers to the unified Bengal - Bardhman, Rarh, Banga. Basically to be understood as todays West Bengal and East Bengal.

Answer (score 4):

From [this blog](https://jagannathpurihkm.wordpress.com/2015/04/13/who-are-gaudiya-vaishnavas/) which answers Who are Gaudiya Vaishnavas?

> “Gauḍīya” indicates the part of India between the southern side of the
> Himalayan Mountains and the northern part of the Vindhyā Hills, which
> is called Āryāvarta, or the Land of the Āryans. This portion of India
> is divided into five parts or provinces (Pañca-gauḍadeśa): Sārasvata
> (Kashmir and Punjab),Kānyakubja (Uttar Pradesh, including the modern
> city of Lucknow), Madhya-gauḍa (Madhya Pradesh), Maithila (Bihar and
> part of Bengal) and Utkala (part of Bengal and the whole of Orissa).
> Bengal is sometimes called Gauḍadeśa, partly because it forms a
> portion of Maithila and partly because the capital of the Hindu king
> Rāja Lakṣmaṇa Sena was known as Gauḍa. This old capital later came to
> be known as Gauḍapura and gradually Māyāpur.
>
> The devotees of Orissa are called Uḍiyās, the devotees of Bengal are
> called Gauḍīyas, and the devotees of southern India are known as
> Drāviḍa devotees.

So the word “Gauḍīya” in Gauḍīya Vaiṣhṇavism refers to a geographic area known as Gauḍadeśa.

Here is a map I found where kingdom of WB is known as Gauda Kingdom.

[image]

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauda_Kingdom

Answer (score 1):

**Gaudiya indicates that they honour Radharani along with Sri Krishna**

A Krishna centric devotee is technically called  a  *”Karshnav”*

Someone who worships Radharani along with Krishna,is called a **Gaudiya** Vaishnav.

[This is explained in a lecture by HG Amogh Lila Prabhu,6:10-6:49](https://youtu.be/hX9yGflxPHo)

Comment: **"We're the true Shaktas"**, how haughtily he says that - What does that even mean IDK - this is exactly the kind of unbelievable nonsense which one can frequently hear from their discourses.

Comment: @Vivikta I don’t mean to denigrate or highlight anyone/any sect,but I thought it may answer the question.I think HG explains it further...,but does it answer your question,though??

Comment: No no, dw, I'm not offended by your answer. It's just what I felt for the "lecturer's choice of words". How can Bhakti for the sweetest deity within Hinduism (i.e., Krishna - *reads Madhurashtkama*) make someone so bitter and critical of other sects and deities? I have always wondered.

Comment: @Hmm.Bur does it answer your question though(or is there more)?(On a side note,most sects think that they are right,so it follows naturally for them too.)

Comment: @Vivikta I think HG’s intention was not a statement to degrade others though....

Comment: Maybe he didn't intend that, anyway your answer does not satisfactorily answer my questions. But I'll upvote since you took effort to give an answer :)

Comment: @Vivikta So what more is it that you seek??

Comment: An answer should be complete in all aspects:: as per the motifs of the asker OP. It does not answer all of my posed questions.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 reasons.
Number 1 - Because Bengal is called Gauda Pradesh therefore the Sampradaya of Gauda is Gaudiya Vaishnava Sampradaya.  North is Gauda and south in Dravida.

Number 2- Gaudiya Vaishnava Sampradaya is a lineage of the Madhva Sampradaya, our Acharyas have explained that one name of Sripad Madhvacharya is Gaudaprajna therefore the Word Gaudiya Sampradaya is Very Appropriate.

Hare Krishna!

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism SE! Please add authentic sources to support your answer.